# Java LWJGL 2D VBO's Slow FPS Performance

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

a friend and I are currently working on some LWJGL 2D related things. I was working on VBOs and was able to get it to work. Now when using this to draw tiles, they work. however, my FPS drops significantly. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my code.

```
public void drawTextureRect(float x, float y, float width, float height,
        String textureName) {
    // Bind the texture to draw
    texture = loadTexture(textureName);
    texture.bind();

    // Set triangle vertex data
    FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6);
    vertices.put(new float[] { x, y, x + width, y, x, height + y });

    // Set texture coordinates
    FloatBuffer textcoord = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6);
    textcoord.put(new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 });
    // Allow OpenGL to interpret the Text Coordinates & Vertex Data
    textcoord.flip();
    vertices.flip();


    int VertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    int TextureHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TextureHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textcoord, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexHandle);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TextureHandle);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    // Enable Vertex and Texture Arrays
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Draw Triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    // Unable Vertex and Textures
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    /*  SECOND TRIANGLE */
    // Set Second Triangle Coordinates
    FloatBuffer vertices2 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6);
    vertices2.put(new float[] { x + width, y + height, x, height + y,
            x + width, y });

    // Set Second Texture Coordinates
    FloatBuffer textcoord2 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6);
    textcoord2.put(new float[] { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 });

    // Allow OpenGl to interpret the Text Coordinates & Vertex Data
    textcoord2.flip();
    vertices2.flip();

    int VertexHandle2 = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexHandle2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    int TexCord = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TexCord);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textcoord2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexHandle2);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TexCord);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    // Enable Vertex and Texture Arrays
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Draw Triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    // Unable Vertex and Textures
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDeleteBuffers(TextureHandle);
    glDeleteBuffers(TexCord);
    glDeleteBuffers(VertexHandle);
    glDeleteBuffers(VertexHandle2);
}`
```

Comment: What do you expect? You're creating *four buffer objects*, and you're doing it *every frame*.

Comment: Ohhh well that explains a lot. Thanks. But I'm new to this stuff and was wondering if you had any suggestions on how I can fix it? Thanks again.

Comment: Moreover, depending on how this `loadTexture (...)` method is implemented, you might be loading texture data on every frame too. You need to think about re-structuring your code to keep data persistently :)

Comment: Yes I checked it right now its definitely loading the texture data on every frame. This is going to be a little more complicated than I expected. lol. Thanks.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Okay so I fixed the code, and it's now NOT loading every frame. Now I'm getting 60FPS again. Thanks again. I now have to figure away to not create a VBO every frame. Thank you again :)